# CS50 PSet 2 - Vigenere - Making sure keyword is alphabetical

Tags: c, if-statement, cs50, vigenere

I'm currently working on the Vigenere cipher in CS50 using the language C. The requirement is to make a program which enciphers some plaintext based on a keyword (both of which the user inputs). It will encipher based on the Vigenere cipher. I'm finding it hard to describe in words what the Vigenere cipher is so here is an example from the CS50 specification:

If Vigenère himself wanted to say HELLO to someone confidentially, using a keyword of, say, ABC, he would encrypt the H with a key of 0 (i.e., A), the E with a key of 1 (i.e., B), and the first L with a key of 2 (i.e., C), at which point he’d be out of letters in the keyword, and so he’d reuse (part of) it to encrypt the second L with a key of 0 (i.e., A) again, and the O with a key of 1 (i.e., B) again. And so he’d write HELLO as HFNLP.

The keyword has to be a string of all alphabetical letters and must be given as the second command-line argument, i.e. argv[1] in my code below. The problem I'm having is that I can't get the program to reject the key if it isn't alphabetical and to continue if it is all alphabetical. I have tried doing it like this (see code below) and it's not returning the printf error message if I include a number in argv[1]. Please can someone offer some advice on what is wrong? Apologies if the format isn't great..

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// declare command line argument variables
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

string k = argv[1];

//return error if there aren't two command line arguments
if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere k\n");
        return 1;
    }

//make sure key is all alphabetical
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(k); i++)

 {
    if(isalpha(k[i]))
    {
    return 0;
    }

    else
    {
    return 1;
    printf("Please ensure all characters are alphabetical.\n");
    }
 }
}
```

I also tried it like this instead of what is inside the for loop above and it didn't work:

```
if(!isalpha(k[i]))
    {
    return 1;
    printf("Please ensure all characters are alphabetical.\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if(isalpha(k[i]))
    {
    return 0;
    }
```

exits the program as soon as there's an alphabet in `argv[1]`. Instead you want to continue the loop until *all* the characters are checked. So, do:

```
 for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(k); i++)
 {
    if(!isalpha(k[i]))
    {
    printf("Please ensure all characters are alphabetical.\n");
    return 1;
    }
 }
```

You also need to put the argument checking *before* you use `argv[1]`.

```
if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere k\n");
        return 1;
    }

string k = argv[1];
...
```

Comment: thank you for helping :) I obviously didn't understand what return really did.

Comment: I modified the `if` statement to not break immediately when it finds a alpha char and fail immediately when there's a non-alpha char. Basically, when the loop completes, `argv[1]` passed the alpha test.

Comment: Sorry one more thing - what is size_t?

Comment: `size_t` is an integer type; used it instead of `int` because technically the loop could overflow an `int` since `strlen()` returns `size_t`. It's probably doesn't matter in your toy program but better to get into the habit of using correct types.

Comment: Quirky objection — in practice, there are very few systems, and no desktop or server systems, where the executable isn't told about its program name, so `argc` is always at least one, even when no arguments are passed, so `argv[1]` is defined as the null pointer (because `argv[argc] == NULL`). So, in this case, it was OK to use `string k = argv[1];` before checking the number of arguments.  However, using `argv[2]` would not necessarily be safe.  And as a general policy, you're correct — check that the argument you're about to use exists before trying to use it.  So, you're basically right.